# Switching activities while running AsyncTask can leak memory?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I am trying to work with `AsyncTask` using inner class. But I face a problem with **Leak Memory**. So I decided to write some test code in order to figure out where issue could be. In this code below i have tried to run a task that counts from 0 to 100. Than I left the activity while the task was running. I got an `_InterruptedException_` and `Activity` leaked(using Leak Canary), then my app was freezed until it crashed. I could not understand why, because the task was canceled, bevor I left the activity.

Here is my little sample code:

```cs
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
BackgroundTask _task;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

   _task = new BackgroundTask(textView);
    _task.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    _task.cancel(true);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (_task.isCancelled()){
        _task = new BackgroundTask(textView);
        _task.execute();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<TextView> _textView;

    public BackgroundTask(TextView textView) {
        this._textView = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return "DONE";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        TextView textView = _textView.get();
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(values[0] + " .");
        }
        Log.d("==> ",values[0]+" ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView = _textView.get();
          if (textView != null) {
             textView.setText(result);
    }
        //MainActivity.this.isFinishing();
    }
  }

 }
```

Here is my log:

```
D/==>: 0 
D/==>: 1 
D/==>: 2 
W/System.err: java.lang.InterruptedException
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
W/System.err:     at com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
W/System.err:     at com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:47)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 343(27KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 82% free, 1267KB/7MB, paused 488us total 18.818ms
I/art: hprof: heap dump "/storage/emulated/0/Download/leakcanary-com.example.longluong.test_app/0a1c4ebe-238f-4156-a317-ed8d454de769_pending.hprof" starting...
I/art: hprof: heap dump completed (12MB) in 7.001s
D/LeakCanary: In com.example.longluong.test_app:1.0:1.
D/LeakCanary: * com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity has leaked:
D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT thread java.lang.Thread.<Java Local> (named 'AsyncTask #1')
D/LeakCanary: * references com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.this$0
D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity instance
D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 6.7 KB.
D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: 4db87806-d761-42c8-a874-9682d7477106
D/LeakCanary: * Device: LENOVO Lenovo Lenovo TB2-X30F TB2-X30F
D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 6.0.1 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.5 00f37f5
D/LeakCanary: * Durations: watch=5055ms, gc=125ms, heap dump=7205ms, analysis=26304ms
D/LeakCanary: * Details:
D/LeakCanary: * Instance of java.lang.Thread
D/LeakCanary: |   static NANOS_PER_MILLI = 1000000
D/LeakCanary: |   static defaultUncaughtHandler = com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler@583012736 (0x22c01180)
D/LeakCanary: |   static count = 902
D/LeakCanary: |   static MAX_PRIORITY = 10
D/LeakCanary: |   static $staticOverhead = byte[48]@1873454545 (0x6faaa5d1)
D/LeakCanary: |   static NORM_PRIORITY = 5
D/LeakCanary: |   static MIN_PRIORITY = 1
D/LeakCanary: |   contextClassLoader = dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@583019904 (0x22c02d80)
D/LeakCanary: |   daemon = false
D/LeakCanary: |   group = java.lang.ThreadGroup@1871611928 (0x6f8e8818)
D/LeakCanary: |   hasBeenStarted = true
D/LeakCanary: |   id = 900
D/LeakCanary: |   inheritableValues = null
D/LeakCanary: |   interruptActions = java.util.ArrayList@584600480 (0x22d84ba0)
D/LeakCanary: |   localValues = java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values@584600512 (0x22d84bc0)
D/LeakCanary: |   lock = java.lang.Object@583012608 (0x22c01100)
D/LeakCanary: |   name = java.lang.String@584594240 (0x22d83340)
D/LeakCanary: |   nativePeer = -1218480552
D/LeakCanary: |   parkBlocker = null
D/LeakCanary: |   parkState = 1
D/LeakCanary: |   priority = 5
D/LeakCanary: |   stackSize = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   target = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@583008752 (0x22c001f0)
D/LeakCanary: |   uncaughtHandler = null
D/LeakCanary: |   shadow$_klass_ = java.lang.Thread
D/LeakCanary: |   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
D/LeakCanary: * Instance of com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity$BackgroundTask
D/LeakCanary: |   static $staticOverhead = byte[16]@583275521 (0x22c41401)
D/LeakCanary: |   static serialVersionUID = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   static $change = null
D/LeakCanary: |   _textView = java.lang.ref.WeakReference@584490912 (0x22d69fa0)
D/LeakCanary: |   this$0 = com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity@583586560 (0x22c8d300)
D/LeakCanary: |   mCancelled = java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean@584499616 (0x22d6c1a0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mFuture = android.os.AsyncTask$3@583016640 (0x22c020c0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mStatus = android.os.AsyncTask$Status@1871859248 (0x6f924e30)
D/LeakCanary: |   mTaskInvoked = java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean@584499632 (0x22d6c1b0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mWorker = android.os.AsyncTask$2@583012640 (0x22c01120)
D/LeakCanary: |   shadow$_klass_ = com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity$BackgroundTask
D/LeakCanary: |   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
D/LeakCanary: * Instance of com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity
D/LeakCanary: |   static $staticOverhead = byte[16]@584134657 (0x22d13001)
D/LeakCanary: |   static serialVersionUID = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   static $change = null
D/LeakCanary: |   _task = com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity$BackgroundTask@583008704 (0x22c001c0)
D/LeakCanary: |   textView = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@584087552 (0x22d07800)
D/LeakCanary: |   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23@583064160 (0x22c0da60)
D/LeakCanary: |   mEatKeyUpEvent = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mResources = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mThemeId = 2131230877
D/LeakCanary: |   mCreated = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentController@584499648 (0x22d6c1c0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1@584490944 (0x22d69fc0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mMediaController = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mPendingFragmentActivityResults = android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat@584490976 (0x22d69fe0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mReallyStopped = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mResumed = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mRetaining = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mStopped = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedActivityFromFragment = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedIntentSenderFromFragment = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mActionBar = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mActionModeTypeStarting = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@584475392 (0x22d66300)
D/LeakCanary: |   mActivityTransitionState = android.app.ActivityTransitionState@584326848 (0x22d41ec0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mApplication = com.example.longluong.test_app.LeakyApp@584548416 (0x22d78040)
D/LeakCanary: |   mCalled = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mChangingConfigurations = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName@584499664 (0x22d6c1d0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration@584503552 (0x22d6d100)
D/LeakCanary: |   mDecor = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   mDefaultKeySsb = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mDestroyed = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mEmbeddedID = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mEnterTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1871616672 (0x6f8e9aa0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mExitTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1871616672 (0x6f8e9aa0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mFinished = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mFragments = android.app.FragmentController@584499680 (0x22d6c1e0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.os.Handler@584548448 (0x22d78060)
D/LeakCanary: |   mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mIdent = 115814648
D/LeakCanary: |   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@584499696 (0x22d6c1f0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation@584284208 (0x22d37830)
D/LeakCanary: |   mIntent = android.content.Intent@584326912 (0x22d41f00)
D/LeakCanary: |   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread@583020800 (0x22c03100)
D/LeakCanary: |   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList@584548480 (0x22d78080)
D/LeakCanary: |   mManagedDialogs = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mMenuInflater = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mParent = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mReferrer = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mResultCode = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   mResultData = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mResumed = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mSearchEvent = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mSearchManager = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedActivity = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mStopped = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mTemporaryPause = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mTitle = java.lang.String@584548512 (0x22d780a0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mTitleColor = 0
D/LeakCanary: |   mTitleReady = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy@584548544 (0x22d780c0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mTranslucentCallback = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread@1933361752 (0x733cc258)
D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleBehind = false
D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleFromClient = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleFromServer = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mVoiceInteractor = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@583319712 (0x22c4c0a0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mWindowAdded = true
D/LeakCanary: |   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl@584548576 (0x22d780e0)
D/LeakCanary: |   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater@584483648 (0x22d68340)
D/LeakCanary: |   mOverrideConfiguration = null
D/LeakCanary: |   mResources = android.content.res.Resources@584284288 (0x22d37880)
D/LeakCanary: |   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme@584548608 (0x22d78100)
D/LeakCanary: |   mThemeResource = 2131230877
D/LeakCanary: |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@584475520 (0x22d66380)
D/LeakCanary: |   shadow$_klass_ = com.example.longluong.test_app.MainActivity
D/LeakCanary: |   shadow$_monitor_ = 1266075474
D/LeakCanary: * Excluded Refs:
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.net.ConnectivityManager.sInstance
D/LeakCanary: | Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Thread:FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Thread:main (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Thread:LeakCanary-Heap-Dump (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Class:java.lang.ref.WeakReference (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Class:java.lang.ref.SoftReference (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Class:java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Class:java.lang.ref.Finalizer (always)
D/LeakCanary: | Class:java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference (always)
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using a View from the Activity which was close?

Comment: Post error code. Are you pressing back button or home to left the activity?

Comment: You want to perform any background task and if I move to second activity then that task should not be canceled right?

Comment: @Jonas452 I have already tested it without taking any reference View from Activity. But it did not change anything. T_T

Comment: I think you are just crashing your app by interupting the sleeping thread. try with Thread.wait and or cancel(false). Also post your LeakCannary error log

Comment: @JayminPanchal I was wondering If i do that, will my app run slowly?

Comment: @LongLuong No your app will not run slowly and also you can perform the separate task in background and user can navigate to any activity

Comment: As an aside note, you may want to mark your inner class as `static` to ensure it does not have an implicit reference to `MainActivity`, or move the task to its own class file entirely.

Comment: have you checked `_textView` is null when you go to SecondActivity.. without a textView if you just loop/keep a timer and increment numbers to 100 and log them it should work. you leak memory cuz that tv  i guess.

Comment: @Charuka I also tried not to update UI in AsyncTask. So i took all textView out of code. But it still showed me that the app was freezed. I guess textView is not the problem.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560611/android-retained-headless-fragment), might help.

Comment: @PravinD Correct. I use back button to leave the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `InterruptedException` your `for` loop is still looping, when you are publishing your progress your thread is cancelled so you need to check whether your thread is cancelled or not.

When your application crashes you still have a `WeakReference` of your `TextView` that's why you have a memory leak. You need to clear your `WeakReference` in `onPostExecute` and `onCancelled`.

Change your:

`doInBackground` to

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        if(isCancelled())
            break;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // After 1 second may be thread is cancelled
            if(!isCancelled()) 
                publishProgress(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    return "DONE";
}
```

`onProgressUpdate` to

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    if(_textView != null){
        TextView textView = _textView.get();
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(values[0] + " .");
        }
        Log.d("==> ",values[0]+" ");
    }
}
```

`onPostExecute` to

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // safe check
    if(_textView != null){
        TextView textView = _textView.get();
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(result);
        _textView.clear();
    }
    _textView = null;
}
```

And add `onCancelled`

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    // safe check
    super.onCancelled();
    if(_textView != null)
        _textView.clear();
    _textView = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But are you sure that _textView.clear() inside onProgressUpdate() is in right position? Because my textView does not change

Comment: And after leaving activity i still got an **W/System.err: java.lang.InterruptedException** in my log. Is that normal?

Comment: Sorry my bad, remove `_textView.clear()` from `onProgressUpdate`. Yeah log is normal.

Comment: I thought GC will track my _textView and kill it. That is what weakReference does.